# Delimiter in CustomLabel

Tags: process-builder, case

I have a custom label which has the following values with the delimiter % in the start and the end.

```
%@gmail.com%%@yahoo.com%%noreply@sfdc.com%%nobody@amazon.com%
```

Now I want to execute a process builder if the case's contact email does not contain any of the above. I created a formula field to store only the domain value. The formula field is as follows:

```
SUBSTITUTE( Contact.Email , LEFT(Contact.Email, FIND("@", Contact.Email)), NULL)
```

For the first two values in the custom label , with the above formula field I execute the process builder correctly. But for the next two values I don't know how to include those in my PB condition. Here is my PB condition:

```
OR((!CONTAINS($Label.Excluded_ContactEmail1, '%' & [Case].ContactEmail   & '%' )),
(!CONTAINS($Label.Excluded_ContactEmail1, '%@' & [Case].domain_name1__c   & '%' )))
```

Comment: Please be advised that this forum is not for emergencies and it is not considered polite to request urgent help. I  have edited your post and remved your urgent help request.

Comment: take a look at the [AccountRegion formula here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=useful_advanced_formulas_acct_mgmt.htm&type=5) for an alternate coding approach

Comment: @cropredy The values in the custom label will get increased. So I think I cannot add all the values statically in my process builder condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for my question. So I just wanted to share with you people. I have created two custom labels here.In one custom label only the domain value is included and in the other, full email addresses are included.

```
Custom Label 1 - %@gmail.com%%@yahoo.com%
Custom Label 2 - %noreply@sfdc.com%%nobody@amazon.com%
```